# How to properly pass UIImage between ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uistoryboardsegue

Trying to pass a `UIImage` between `ViewControllers` through a `UITapGesture`. I have added the `UITapGesture` successfully, however, my segue refuses to perform.

Here is my code in the initial view:

```
var image: UIImage!

func imageTapped() {

        println("it works!")


         func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if (segue == "enlargePhoto") {

                let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EnlargedPhotoViewController

                destinationVC.bigImage = image


            }else {

                println("your code sucksssss!")
            }

        }
    }
```

Code for destinationVC:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class EnlargedPhotoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var enlargedHomeImage: UIImageView!

    var bigImage: UIImage!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.enlargedHomeImage!.image = self.bigImage

    }
```

Any idea as to why my `UIImage` fails to pass? Everything looks fine to me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `prepareForSegue` as a nested function, it is not called by the framework, and that's why you don't get your image passed to the destination. The correct way is to implement `prepareForSegue` in the class-wise scope (the same scope as your `imageTapped`. Just put `prepareForSegue` outside of the curly brace of `imageTapped` like this:

```
func imageTapped() {
    // Perform the segue
}

func prepareForSegue() {
// Pass the image reference
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Let me test it out. Thanks for your input.

Comment: By doing that.. Will I have to set segue to UIStoryboard() and sender: AnyObject?

Comment: No. Your posted declaration is correct. The problem is just the scope.

Comment: Thanks! Beginner mistake.